# How to get the type from array of objects in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript, object, types

In TypeScript, I have arrays of objects like this

```
const props1 = [
  { propName: 'id', propValue: 1 },
  { propName: 'name', propValue: 'John' },
  { propName: 'age', propValue: 30 }
];

const props2 = [
  { propName: 'id', propValue: 2 },
  { propName: 'role', propValue: 'admin' }
];

const props3 = [
  { propName: 'job', propValue: 'developer' },
  { propName: 'salary', propValue: 1000 }
];
```

I want to create a function `createObject` that I can pass an array of them to it, and it should return an object that its keys are `propName` with values `propValue`

This is the desirable results type

```
const obj1 = createObject(props1); // Returned type should be: { id: number; name: string; age: number }
const obj2 = createObject(props2); // Returned type should be: { id: number; role: string }
const obj3 = createObject(props3); // Returned type should be: { job: string; salary: number }
```

This is my try, but doesn't return the correct type

```
function createObject<T extends { propName: string; propValue: any }[]>(propertiesObject: T) {
  const obj: { [key: string]: any } = {};

  for (const { propName, propValue } of propertiesObject) {
    obj[propName] = propValue;
  }

  return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing we need to do is change the arrays. Currently, each `propName` is only of type `string` and there is no way to extract the original literal type.

We need to initialize them with `as const`.

```
const props1 = [
  { propName: 'id', propValue: 1 },
  { propName: 'name', propValue: 'John' },
  { propName: 'age', propValue: 30 }
] as const

const props2 = [
  { propName: 'id', propValue: 2 },
  { propName: 'role', propValue: 'admin' }
] as const

const props3 = [
  { propName: 'job', propValue: 'developer' },
  { propName: 'salary', propValue: 1000 }
] as const
```

Now the actual function.

```
type ToPrimitive<T> =
  T extends string ? string
  : T extends number ? number
  : T extends boolean ? boolean
  : T;

function createObject<
  T extends readonly { propName: string; propValue: any }[]
>(propertiesObject: T): { 
  [K in T[number] as K["propName"]]: ToPrimitive<K["propValue"]> 
} {
  const obj: { [key: string]: any } = {};

  for (const { propName, propValue } of propertiesObject) {
    obj[propName] = propValue;
  }

  return obj as { [K in T[number] as K["propName"]]: ToPrimitive<K["propValue"]> };
}
```

We also need to add `readonly` to the constraint of `T` to allow our `as const` arrays. The return type is a simple mapped type which maps over the elements `K` of `T[number]` and uses `K["propName"]` as the keys.

`K["propValue"]` currently also holds the narrowed literal types. But we actually want to widen them here back to their primitive types. That's where `ToPrimitive` comes into play.

The return type is now quite complex. TypeScript is not able to correlate it to the implementation anymore. That's why the type assertion at the end is needed.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgJxHCBGGBeGBtAUDGAb3iTgDkBDAWwFMAuGAcgEsATRgGhOQDUKAbAK70Y6AL4d8RbuWojGYOZxl8h8gFIgAFmEYwJU4omSVaDRhQDmNZcbirhDAMwAGfbgC6MChBihIULi4-tAyEABMmDiGMqbybLakDiKRBgRGpHHmSPw2XHbJ5hSsVMy67l4+fuDQQSGwdhBOUXjpsXLmAFYgAEaJvAKOTKw0AG40-Mg0CHpp0nZZTBACFAgAnv32gyKoLnsV3r71QVBrcDQwACogAAoIzKVQzOMAPJcAfJhSlzA0AB5QGhgVi+aD3MCWGAAfhgYLKlikDB+-0BwN8YEEVB602hMAxWOmiKuvwBQJBMB6IBAuQoYFxlOpNFpRMuAG4ggAzQRgYBPcB+BBMwEAeR6nRovJe3xJqPJguK4H4a3mmQ6sKg4MsrJU2wYtOVYmwHlw7wAFHZpk8aBBReLeUiAJQMYjYADSMDKV2w+OxCEqvld2AARAs5EGPB4kbd7o9njQXoGQ0ltuHPmIiFJ6jBep1nTgANY0NYMOEQyPeMAGqKEMTsqQckAIGCmrMZExyfLJtT6bMcmSW5jW20SqAOjMEAg57Ch2heLAFbbsghiIIEQVQQQIOk5w7SN0eumXb2Y33+mCJmc0cPl653B7MJ6vC9d4Sp-TslfBGqwHPoLDAeURTFEdzVINAHW1AB6SCYAAJRoDctxoVgYFOc5YS0EBBH4FDsTzNgGB9aZtUUMx1U1bUrBEIimxXLMc0if9AJoYdeVA5AIggmBoLghDNzAZDULOC4IEw7DcJEYgCLxE9iJgHIRFLSE6O-bMxWaJihRY4C2MaJwuJ4+DEIElC0JEsScIpSSYG6HoSw1eFtWWfhVmLGSCVooIgA)

Answer (score 1):

When you return the object at the end, you can use a mapped type to create a key in an object type for each `T[number]` in the argument. `['propName']` can be used to extract the key on the left-hand side, and ['propValue']` will extract the value.

```
const props1 = [
  { propName: 'id', propValue: 1 },
  { propName: 'name', propValue: 'John' },
  { propName: 'age', propValue: 30 }
] as const;
function createObject<T extends readonly { propName: string; propValue: unknown }[]>(propertiesObject: T) {
  const obj: { [key: string]: unknown } = {};

  for (const { propName, propValue } of propertiesObject) {
    obj[propName] = propValue;
  }

  return obj as {
    [K in T[number] as K['propName']]: K['propValue']
  };
}

const obj1 = createObject(props1); // Returned type should be: { id: number; name: string; age: number }
```

If

```
const obj1: {
    id: 1;
    name: "John";
    age: 30;
}
```

is too specific, and you want just `number` and `string` in the values instead, you could either change the typing of the `props1`, eg

```
const props1 = [
  { propName: 'id', propValue: 1 as number },
  { propName: 'name', propValue: 'John' as string },
  { propName: 'age', propValue: 30 as number }
] as const;
```

Or create a utility type that widens strings to `string` and numbers to `number`.

```
type Widen<T extends unknown> =
    T extends string ? string
  : T extends number ? number
  // etc
  : T;
```

```
  return obj as {
    [K in T[number] as K['propName']]: Widen<K['propValue']>
  };
```